# Expo IOS tracking location with app killed?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, location, tracking

Currently using expo-location and task manager and am able to get location updates with App Killed on Android, but it is only working in foreground on IOS. Has anyone else been able to tackle this problem that could share a library or article you followed? I'm about 3 days in the hole on this issue already and it's only causing a problem on iOS. Thanks if you have any suggestions!